# C# SocketAsyncEventHandler evaluate operation on Complete

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await, socketasynceventargs

How do you evaluate if a Socket operation was successful or not with [SocketAsyncEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs)?
Do you evaluate the SocketAsyncEventArgs you passed as parameter?

```
SocketasyncEventArgs saea = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
socket.ConnectAsync(saea);
saea.Completed += (sender, args) => 
{
    if(saea.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        // fail
}
```

Or do you evaluate the SocketAsyncEventArgs from the [Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.completed) event?

```
saea.Completed += (sender, args) => 
{
    if(args.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        // fail
}
```

Or both? What does it mean if one shows success and the other not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that you need to subscribe the event *before* you call the `*Async` method (`ConnectAsync` in this case), and you **must** check the return value from the `*Async` method - the `true` vs `false` indicates whether it completed synchronously or not; if it completes synchronously, it **will not** invoke your callback - it is expected that *you* will invoke any required code.

As for the question: use the `args` in the event. The main reason for this is efficiency; the first example uses a "captured variable", which means it needs a capture context instance and a delegate instance per subscription. The second example does *not* use a captured variable, and as such the compiler optimizes the delegate creation to use a single static event handler instance for *all* subscriptions.

Comment: makes sense. But in theory the result should be the same either way, right?

Comment: yes, same result, but the non-capture version is more effiicent

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the SocketAsyncEventArgs from the Completed event is the same object like the call parameter? I'm wondering about cleanup and stuff. When do I need to dispose the SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Comment: @Josh yes, it is the same instance